How to create metric in kairosdb
Im a green hand in kairosdb,I want to know how to create a metric.
I read the documention and use postman send the request but I can't fint the metric I create.
I think, use the RestfulApi can add the metric into the table.Is my method error?
enter image description here

Welcome, Toki. Please convert images into text or into code.

thanks a lot, i have already know how to do

maybe to share or to delete this question?
